# $timeout, triggering app initialization in angular directive test and $httpBackend mock error

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive

I'm having an issue with a test (Karma+Mocha+Chai). I'm testing a pretty simple directive, part of a bigger angular module (webapp). The issue is that, when calling `$timeout.flush()` in my test, the module/app get's initialized and makes a request to get the template for the homepage. As `$httpBackend` (part of ng-mock) is not expecting any request it fails:

```
Unexpected request: GET /partials/homepage
No more request expected
$httpBackend@/Users/doup/Sites/projects/visitaste-web/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1208:1
...
continues
```

**How is possible that a directive is triggering the module initialization??** Any idea how to avoid this issue? Preferably without cutting this code into another module.

Thanks!

---

Here the directive:

```
module.exports = ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', // only for attribute names
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
            $scope.$on('vtFocus', function (event, id) {
                if (id === attrs.vtFocus) {
                    $timeout(function () {
                        element.focus();
                    }, 0, false);
                }
            });
        }
    };
}];
```

And here the actual test:

```
describe('vtFocus', function() {
    var $scope, $timeout, element;

    beforeEach(module('visitaste'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($injector, $compile, $rootScope) {
        $scope   = $rootScope.$new();
        $timeout = $injector.get('$timeout');
        element  = angular.element('<input vt-focus="my-focus-id"/>');

        $compile(element)($scope);
    }));

    it('should focus the element when a vtFocus event is broadcasted with the correct focus ID', function () {
        expect(element.is(':focus')).to.be.false;
        $scope.$broadcast('vtFocus', 'my-focus-id');
        $timeout.flush();
        expect(element.is(':focus')).to.be.true;
    });

    it('should NOT focus the element when a vtFocus event is broadcasted with a different focus ID', function () {
        expect(element.is(':focus')).to.be.false;
        $scope.$broadcast('vtFocus', 'wrong-id');
        $timeout.flush();
        expect(element.is(':focus')).to.be.false;
    });

});
```

This is the part where I configure UI-Router for path `/` in `app.config()`:

```
// ...

$stateProvider
.state('homepage', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: '/partials/homepage',
});

// ...
```

Comment: Where is the code that makes the request for `/partials/homepage`? Is that in one of your controllers? It's probably the `$scope.broadcast()` that is triggering a digest in your controller. But the question is why is your controller being instantiated here? I've had this problem while testing a controller (not a directive). In that scenario it makes perfect sense why the request is generated, and so I just expect that request in the test.

Comment: I'm not instanciating any controller in the test neither in the directive, I'm talkin about a directive here. The `/partials/homepage` it's not referenced directly, I suppose that it's being called by UI-Router while initializing path `/`. What I don't get is why my `$broadcast` triggers App/UI-Router init, the event should go from parent to child (hence `broadcast`) and the `$scope` in the test it's not related to any other scope.

Comment: Anyway, the code under test it's quite irrelevant, I know it works and it's not critical, but I want to know why is this happening, since this has happened in another test, issue which affortunately I was able to circumvent.

But it's a signal that something it's not OK. I'm doing something wrong. :-(

Comment: Yes I know you are not instantiating a controller in the test. I am asking which part of your code calls the template at `/partials/homepage`? That just might give us a clue as to why the request is being made.

Comment: @sunil-d I've a route defined via [UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for `/` which loads `/partials/homepage` template (in `config()`), but I haven't associated any controller for the route. It's like `$timeout` bootstraps the app or something...  but only when it's called, not before (!!!). Ohhh, this is confusing. ^_^

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I just moved the directives into it's own module `visitaste.directives` and loaded that module in the test, so now it's sepparated from UI-Router and it doesn't trigger a request to the template.

Still I'll wait for another solution, before I accept this answer.

```
describe('vtFocus', function() {
    var $scope, $timeout, element;

    beforeEach(module('visitaste.directives'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope, _$timeout_) {
        $scope   = $rootScope.$new();
        $timeout = _$timeout_;
        element  = angular.element('<input vt-focus="my-focus-id"/>');
        element.appendTo(document.body);

        $compile(element)($scope);
    }));

    afterEach(function () {
        element.remove();
    });

    it('should focus the element when a vtFocus event is broadcasted with the correct focus ID', function () {
        expect(document.activeElement === element[0]).to.be.false;
        $scope.$broadcast('vtFocus', 'my-focus-id');
        $timeout.flush();
        expect(document.activeElement === element[0]).to.be.true;
    });

    it('should NOT focus the element when a vtFocus event is broadcasted with a different focus ID', function () {
        expect(document.activeElement === element[0]).to.be.false;
        $scope.$broadcast('vtFocus', 'wrong-id');
        expect(document.activeElement === element[0]).to.be.false;
    });

});
```